# Access Bootstrap 5 variables on Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Using Rails 7 and Bootstrap 5. I want other SCSS to be able to access Bootstrap variables, so that I don't have to redefine again. But with the following setup, I get `Error: Undefined variable:`.

Here's my setup:

```
# application.scss
@import "bootstrap_overrides/bootstrap_custom";
@import "bootstrap_overrides/bootstrap_components";
@import "global";
@import "pages";

# bootstrap_overrides/bootstrap_custom.scss
# this is where I override the default values in Bootstrap variables
# this works fine
$font-family-monospace:  "Ubuntu Mono", SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;

# bootstrap_overrides/bootstrap_components.scss
# basically a copy of https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/main/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss so that I can enable/disable components without bloating the final CSS

@import "bootstrap/mixins/banner";
@include bsBanner("");


// scss-docs-start import-stack
// Configuration
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/variables-dark";
@import "bootstrap/maps";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/utilities";
...

# global.scss
# this is where the problem lies where I can't access $font-family-monospace, nor can I access any bootstrap variables like $black, etc.
.brand {
  font-family: $font-family-monospace;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

EDIT: It works if I put all those four SCSS files together in a subdirectory "bootstrap_overrides", then I can access all variables. But I have to put them in a subdirectory `app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_overrides`

Comment: Heads up: "The Sass team discourages the continued use of the @import rule. Sass will gradually phase it out over the next few years, and eventually remove it from the language entirely. Prefer the @use rule instead.". So to both fix and future proof this code you should switch to the [dart-sass compiler](https://github.com/rails/dartsass-rails) and use [`@use` rules](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/) instead to import the variables into the scopes where you need them.